# counting of rows with group by

Tags: mysql, count, group-by

```
seat_num    service_key   source_id  destination_id
1              19229          0             60 
1              19229          240           600 
2              19229          0             240 
3              19229          0             600
```

my table data is like above. I want get the result as below

```
Count    service_key   source_id  destination_id 
3              19229          0             60
2              19229          240           600 
2              19229          0             240 
3              19229          0             600
```

the logic behind is that count of the seat nums should fall between the range of source and destination. My issue here is 0 to 600 source and destination it is counting as 4 but it should be 3 because same seat num (1) is used twice. so please let me know how to get the result as required.

Comment: Please add your query

Answer (score 0):

**Try this  :**

```
select service_key,source_id,destination_id,count(seat_num) 
from tablename 
where seat_num between source_id and destination_id 
group by seat_num 
having count(seat_num) > 0;
```